# Using Regex to Target HREF Attribute

Tags: php, regex

I'm very new to regex.

I want to target everything in between the quotes in `href=""`, so that I can quickly parse html and replace the contents of link references.

I also want to be able to do this with `img` `src` attributes, but if someone can explain how to do it with `href`, I will be able to do other attributes in the same way.

If I have this markup:

```
<a href="http://my.domain/simple-product-2.html" class="product-image"><img src="http://my.domain/media/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/75x/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/images/catalog/product/placeholder/small_image.jpg" width="75" height="75" alt="Simple Product 2" title="Simple Product 2"></a>
<div class="product-details">
    <h3 class="product-name"><a href="http://my.domain/simple-product-2.html">Simple Product 2</a></h3>
    <div class="price-box">
        <span class="regular-price" id="product-price-2-related">
        <span class="price">$42.00</span>                                    </span>
    </div>
    <p><a href="http://my.domain/wishlist/index/add/product/2/form_key/PLOSE4N7mH4kcOgX/" class="link-wishlist">Add to Wishlist</a></p>
</div>
```

How do I use regex to target any of the values between `""` in something like an `href`??

Edit: expected output as an example:

Given this input

```
href="http://my.domain/simple-product-2.html"
```

Retrieve this output:

```
href="http://index.html"
```

Comment: what is expected output? please share.

Comment: Start to read here http://www.regular-expressions.info/. Learning some Regular Expressions yourself couldn;t hurt.

Comment: output is not a valid url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to target everything in between the quotes in href=""

Get the matched group from index 1 using [possessive quantifiers](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html) as suggested by @lcoderre in below comments.

```
href="([^"]*+)"
```

Here is [online demo](http://regex101.com/r/pV8qU8/21)

---

Try this one as well using [Positive Lookbehind & Lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

```
(?<=href=").*?(?=")
```

[Online demo](http://regex101.com/r/pV8qU8/20)

---

Sample code with first regex pattern:

```
$re = "/href=\\"([^\\"]*+)\\"/m";
$str = ...

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

Comment: For the record, might speed things up with possessive quantifiers (http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html) with this instead: `href="([^"]*+)"`

Comment: yes you are right. Thanks for sharing knowledge. I'll update it in my post as well.

Answer (score 4):

**Do not use regex for parsing HTML**. Use [**DOM parser in PHP**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php):

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$doc->loadHTML( $html ); // loads your html

$nodelist = $doc->getElementsByTagName('a'); // get all the <a> tags
for($i=0; $i < $nodelist->length; $i++) {
    $node = $nodelist->item($i);
    $val = $node->attributes->getNamedItem('href')->nodeValue;
    echo "href is: $val\n";
}
```